# Tasks for tutorial class sessions, not at home

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, translation, academia

Writing worksheets for students at university, I'd like to distinguish tasks intended to be solved in tutorial classes from tasks intended as homework. What would be the appropriate term to refer to non-homework tasks intended for class?

So far my worksheets have been in German, and the term I used was “Präsenzaufgaben”, meaning tasks (“Aufgaben”) intended for when people are present (noun “Präsenz”) in class. But your solution need not be a close translation of this as long as the meaning is clear or the term is established. Preferably both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about "[classwork](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/classwork)" and "[seatwork](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/seatwork)?"

Comment: I'd go for classwork

Comment: In my experience in the US classwork is any homework associated with a class.  This has no regard to where you would do the homework.   It could be in class or out of.  I have never heard of the term seatwork, but I guess it would imply [that you need to be in your seat] better than classwork.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd The term "seatwork" implies work to be done by students at their desks in the classroom.

Comment: To me, “seatwork” somehow suggests a strict setup with each student working on his own at his seat. I prefer students to discuss stuff in groups, without anyone being fixed to his seat, so for this reason I'd intuitively prefer “classwork”. But of course my associations might be completely unfounded, since I hadn't known either term before reading this answer. Unfortunately, those M-W entries you linked to are not available for free, and apparently my university doesn't have a subscription (yet). Will probably have a look at the printed version today.

Comment: @MvG You might want to consider this link then http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/classwork

Answer (score 1):

We preface stuff like this in our corporate LMS with "**in-class**" or "**instructor led**".